# batching DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer

Tags: jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am using a DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer (specifically, OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer) to get the value of the next available primary key before I do an insert.  For performance reasons, I am rewriting the insert queries to be batched.  Is there a similar way to use the DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer to batch retrieve the next couple of primary keys rather than retrieving each individually?

I am using spring-jdbc 3.0.4 on an oracle 10g database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a custom solution based off of the query located here:
https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1115582